# NodeJS + Socket.io, strange reconnect behavior

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I have a websocket server:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(serverPort, {'store' : RedisStore, log: false});   
io.enable('browser client minification');
io.enable('browser client etag');
io.enable('browser client gzip');
io.set('log level', 3); // 0 - error, 1 - warn, 2 - info, 3 - debug
io.set('transports', ['websocket', 'flashsocket', 'htmlfile', 'xhr-polling', 'jsonp-polling']);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socketServer) {
    // application goes here
});
```

I have clients:

```
socketClient = io.connect('http://' + host + ':' + port, {'sync disconnect on unload': true});
```

Everything works fine. I can listening to messages from both sides.

```
socketServer.emit(listener, params); or socketClient.emit(listener, params);
```

But there is a behavior I can't understand. After emitting some messages from server to client and restarting the server, ie CTRL + C and node upServer.js, all messages emitted are emitted again.

Example:

```
socketServer.emit(listener1, params); // client fire listener1
socketServer.emit(listener2, params); // client fire listener2
socketServer.emit(listener3, params); // client fire listener3
```

CTRL + C
node upServer.js

client fire listener1, listener2 and listener3

Someone have a clue about what's going on?

Comment: can you configure the client `force new connection` to `true` and `reconnect` to `false`?

Comment: This is related to heartbeat timeout and reconnect. When you CTRL+C and start your server before heartbeat timeout, your server fires 'connect event' again

Comment: @Phoenix, I will try and see what happens.

Comment: @MOmary, the server emits 'connect' it's ok, but its firing listener1, listener2 and listener3 also.

Comment: Can you edit your question and post more code?

Comment: @Phoenix Cantt use recconet equals false. If the server restart or the forked process was killed, the client will not reconnect.

Comment: @MOmary the code is big, forking process, creating domains, logic to call business objects... 
I guess, when the server restart, client is registering listeners that already exists. Dont know how Socket.io works on this. The existent socket client object reconnect or a new one is created?

Comment: are your events defined right after 'connection' event?? I mean is it like this: io.sockets.on('connection', function (socketServer) {
    socketServer.emit(listener1, params);
socketServer.emit(listener2, params);
socketServer.emit(listener3, params); 
});

Comment: @MOmary No. After connection event the client send parameters about system routine, the server load the bussiness object, create the listeners and emit a ready event to client. After all this, client consume some service and the server emits listener1, listener2 or listener3.

Comment: Found the problem. In my client, when the server reconnected, the client socket object already exists, then I only call a method to register listeners for my business object in server. But the connect event was called by the server and the prior method was called a seccond time. 
PS: Both methods was invoked, connect and reconnect.
Sorry for taking your time with a lame issue. Sorry for my bad english also. Thank you all.